# Bixby authorization access_token too long

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I'm working on a bixby capsule. I have the following `authorization.bxb`

```
authorization{
   user {
    oauth2-authorization-code (Sample Provider) {
      client-id ("BixbyCapsule")
      client-secret-key ("key")
      authorize-endpoint (example.com/oauth2/authorize)
      token-endpoint (example.com/oauth2/token)
    }
  }
}
```

After getting redirected from authorization endpoint and when getting the tokens I am getting the error saying access_token too long for the field. Our token is about 3100 characters long.

```
Org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [INSERT INTO `access_keys` ( `user_id`, `capsule_id`, `provider_hash`, `provider_scope`, `access_token`, `refresh_token`, `expiration` ) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `access_keys`.`access_token` = ?, `access_keys`.`refresh_token` = ?, `access_keys`.`expiration` = ?]; Data truncation: Data too long for column 'access_token' at row 1
```

Since the token contains scope of the token, we can't make the it shorter and it already being used with other virtual assistance.

Is there any workaround to save and use the tokens? or is there anyway I can change the column length of the tokens?

Answer (score 0):

This issue may be specific to your use case. Please reach out to the support team via the Contact Support option in the Help dropdown menu in Bixby Developer Studio.